# Showing horizontal-scrollbar while setting width: 100%

Tags: html, css

I have 3 DIVs (left-panel, content, right-panel) setting across the browser like the HTML below.

The .content class is set 100% width for expending when dock and undock the left-panel and right-panel.  Everything is working well so far.

An issue is: the .content has several elements, they make at the bottom of the browser show a horizontal scrollbar.

Instead of showing the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of browser, please direct me how to make it show at .content DIV so that .left-panel, .content and .right-panel will be visible in the browser. Thanks!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byx2d460/23/)

HTML

```
<div class="table">
    <div>
        <div class="left-panel"><p>Left Panel</p><p>Left Panel</p><p>Left Panel</p><p>Left Panel</p><p>Left Panel</p><p>Left Panel</p><p>Left Panel</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div style="width:100%; background:#ccc; display: inline-flex">
            <div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div style="border:1px solid red;position:absolute;bottom:0">ddddd
        </div>
    </div>
    <div >
        <div class="right-panel"><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table > div{
display: table-cell;
}
.content{
position:relative;
width:100%; border:1px solid red;
overflow: auto;
}
.left-panel, .right-panel{
width:200px;
border:1px solid black;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}

.box {
width: 300px;
border: solid 1px red;
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You looking for something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/byx2d460/33/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your css.

updated left panel, right panel,

width for content is not calculated with calc()

and give margin left to your content.

then add scrollbar to content

```css
.content{
position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 388px);
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 193px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.left-panel{
  left:0;
}
.right-panel{
  right:0;
}
.left-panel, .right-panel{
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.box {
min-width: 300px;
border: solid 1px red;
height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <div class="left-panel"><p>Left Panel</p><p>Left Panel</p><p>Left Panel</p><p>Left Panel</p><p>Left Panel</p><p>Left Panel</p><p>Left Panel</p>
  </div>

    <div class="content">
  <div style="width:100%; background:#ccc; display: inline-flex">
   <div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div><div class="box">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div style="border:1px solid red;position:absolute;bottom:0">ddddd
  </div>
 </div>

  <div class="right-panel"><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p><p>Right Panel</p></div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/byx2d460/27/

Comment: @Sagar, Thank you very much! the scrollbar shows as expected.  Because of `width: calc(100% - 388px);` the scrollbar displays, but when I try to hide one of left or right panel, the `.content` doesn't expend itself. Any idea?

Comment: add some class to the parent div (one containing left, content and right) and update the css accordingly. @abcidd

Answer (score 0):

If you want the horizontal scrollbar inside the content div you have to use the calc function inside the `content` div, like sagar explained bellow.

If you want to make it responsive and don't care about this min-width inside the `box` div use my solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/byx2d460/30/

```
.content{
position:relative;
width:100%; 
border:1px solid red;
overflow: auto;
}
.left-panel, .right-panel{
width:200px;
border:1px solid black;
height:100%;
overflow:auto;
}

.box {
width: 11%;
border: solid 1px red;
height: 100px;
}
```